# How to lock some part of marginpar area?

Tags: geometry, marginpar

Consider the following layout.

[image]

I'd like to lock some part of marginpar area. For example, after 6cm from the top, skip 4cm and the margin area continues below.

Comment: I would use `fancyhdr` (to assure that locked area will be on every page) and `tikz` packages (with a help of absolute positioning).